# Polynomial division in the case of $\frac{x^2 -x}{1-x}$

Tags: polynomials

What is the answer in $$\frac{x^2 - x}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Factor $x^2-x$, and see what you get...

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x^2 - x}{1-x} = \frac{x(x-1)}{1-x} = \frac{-x(1-x)}{1-x} = -x$$